# How to use LIKE operator on a subquery(returning multiple values) inSQL Server

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products
WHERE Industry IN (SELECT * 
                   FROM STRING_SPLIT('Logistics;Retail;Agriculture', ';'))
```

Can I use `LIKE` instead of `IN` in my `WHERE` clause?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use `LIKE` as follows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ';Logistics;Retail;Agriculture;' LIKE '%;' + Industry + ';%';
```

But it would be better to see if you can use a `WHERE IN (...)` construct, which would be sargable, easier to handle, and probably more performant than the above.

Comment: REGEXP is not available in Sql Server

Comment: @BhargavKumar: you didn't mention in your question **what** RDBMS you're using .....